# XPATH python div table

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

Tried a couple of examples from other posts regarding extracting data from tables with selenium, however I don't make it work. Any ideas of how I could extract the data from a table like this with python?
[image]

```
<div class="js--property-table-body project-property-table__body">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="project-property-table__body__loader"></span>
    <div class="property-table">
        <div class="property-table__head">
            <div class="property-table__head__row" v-html="titles">
                <div class="property-table__head__row__item">Nummer</div>
                <div class="property-table__head__row__item">Våning</div>
                <div class="property-table__head__row__item">Antal rum</div>
                <div class="property-table__head__row__item">Storlek</div>
                <div class="property-table__head__row__item">Pris</div>
                <div class="property-table__head__row__item">Avgift</div>
                <div class="property-table__head__row__item">Status</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="property-table__list" v-html="listData">
            <a href="https://www.example.com" class="property-table__list__block property-table__list__block--link ">
                <div class="property-table__list__block__item">
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__heading">Nummer</span>
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__value">11-1001</span></div>
                <div class="property-table__list__block__item">
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__heading">Våning</span>
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__value">0</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-table__list__block__item">
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__heading">Antal rum</span>
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__value">1 rok</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-table__list__block__item">
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__heading">Storlek</span>
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__value">38 kvm</span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-table__list__block__item">
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__heading">Pris</span>
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__value"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-table__list__block__item">
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__heading">Avgift</span>
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__value"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="property-table__list__block__item">
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__heading">Status</span>
                    <span class="property-table__list__block__item__value">Bokad</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question misses some essential information: What you tried. The results or errors you received. What you expect to receive instead. Please add those three things.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to handle tables built up by div class and not <tr><td>

Comment: I didn't come that far with my tests that errors even are of value to present. Others were able to answer my question in an adequate way.... That's amazing. I didn't ignored  your question but the information of relevance in this case is that I don't know to handle tables of div classes. That's how basic it can be for someone not experienced in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the last two rows in your HTML. But to extract the information using selenium and python, based on the HTML given, you could write something like this (though the output is transposed):

```
first_row = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.property-table__list__block__item__heading')

second_row = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.property-table__list__block__item__value')

for i in range(len(first_row)):
    print(first_row[i].text + ' ' + second_row[i].text)
```

**EDIT:** Here is a POC example that will demonstrate how it is possible to scrape all the values from the table. Adapt as you like, in particular I expect you don't want the output in any format like this. But I have just added the print statements to demonstrate all the data's being scraped. Also, you could loop through the columns, creating an array of arrays, instead of defining individual arrays for each column, as I have.

Here is the python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.besqab.se/bostader/hitta-bostad/stockholm/vaxholm/norrberget-skutan/")
heading_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.property-table__list__block__item__heading')
nummer_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(1) > span.property-table__list__block__item__value')
vaning_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(2) > span.property-table__list__block__item__value')
antal_rum_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(3) > span.property-table__list__block__item__value')
storklet_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(4) > span.property-table__list__block__item__value')
pris_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(5) > span.property-table__list__block__item__value')
avgift_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(6) > span.property-table__list__block__item__value')
status_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(7) > span.property-table__list__block__item__value')
for i in range(len(nummer_elements)):
    print(str(heading_elements[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')) + ": " + str(nummer_elements[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    print(str(heading_elements[1].get_attribute('innerHTML')) + ": " + str(vaning_elements[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    print(str(heading_elements[2].get_attribute('innerHTML')) + ": " + str(antal_rum_elements[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    print(str(heading_elements[3].get_attribute('innerHTML')) + ": " + str(storklet_elements[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    print(str(heading_elements[4].get_attribute('innerHTML')) + ": " + str(pris_elements[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    print(str(heading_elements[5].get_attribute('innerHTML')) + ": " + str(avgift_elements[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    print(str(heading_elements[6].get_attribute('innerHTML')) + ": " + str(status_elements[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')))
    print('========')
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Nummer: 11-1001
Våning: 0
Antal rum: 1 rok
Storlek: 38 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
Nummer: 11-1002
Våning: 0
Antal rum: 4 rok
Storlek: 95 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
Nummer: 11-1003
Våning: 0
Antal rum: 3 rok
Storlek: 83 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
Nummer: 11-1004
Våning: 0
Antal rum: 3 rok
Storlek: 87 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
Nummer: 11-1006
Våning: 0
Antal rum: 4 rok
Storlek: 95 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
Nummer: 11-1101
Våning: 1
Antal rum: 1 rok
Storlek: 38 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
Nummer: 11-1102
Våning: 1
Antal rum: 2 rok
Storlek: 52 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
Nummer: 11-1103
Våning: 1
Antal rum: 4 rok
Storlek: 109 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
Nummer: 11-1104
Våning: 1
Antal rum: 4 rok
Storlek: 108 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
Nummer: 11-1201
Våning: 2
Antal rum: 1 rok
Storlek: 36 kvm
Pris:
Avgift:
Status: Bokad
========
```

Is that the data you are wanting?

Comment: I removed the two rows to make the code example shorter. In reality the table is much larger also and the table can be dynamic in length (number of rows)

Comment: I'd need to see the HTML for the rest of the rows in order to help provide code to scrape them.

Comment: This is the page: https://www.besqab.se/bostader/hitta-bostad/stockholm/vaxholm/norrberget-skutan/   I can add the table in the code example if you want? But it will be quite long code.

Comment: @NewDev see my updated code for an example of how this could work.

Comment: thanks. will test this also during the day. I will get back to you

Comment: I seems to work overall, however I get an error message during the third round of the loop. Error at row "print(str(heading_elements[5].get_attribute('innerHTML')) + ": " + str(avgift_elements[i].get_attribute('innerHTML')))" with error message: "StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". Before I get the error, I get two rounds printed which looks good. I just need to put it into a dateframe and CSV for storing also

Comment: Update, when running the script again it works with no error. No idea why it failed before...

Comment: Is this a good solution for you or do you need help getting it in the format you want?

Comment: I think it is good for now. I will try to format the data myself, otherwise I get back  to you. I will give points to your answer when I also have tried the other solution. Since you both spent time on this I want to try both solutions.

Comment: I have one question actually. Since the table can differ from time to time and project to project, which solution would you recommend for making the for loop dynamic and not static to 10? Counting the total number of rows first or making it like a "while"?

Comment: @NewDev Oh, I think it should be easy. Instead of `for i in range(10):`, just put `for i in range(len(nummer_elements)):`... I'll edit that into my answer. My current version of the solution is updated in my answer. It should work provided all the rows have the same number of columns, which seems a reasonable assumption.

Comment: thanks. However it behaves a bit strange, the error with StaleElementReferenceException is back and I get it every time when i do anything with any element, like calculating "len()". The workaround now is put it into a variable "test = len(nummer_elements)" and then run driver.find_elements again for "nummer" and then "for i in range(test):"

Answer (score 1):

If we assume each "a" WebElement is the root of each row

```
with open("the path file.txt","w") as table_file:
    headers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'property-table__head__row']/div")
    for header in headers:
        table_file.write(f"{header.text}\t")
    table_file.write("\n")
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'property-table__list']/a")
    for row in rows:
        entries_of_the row = row.find_elements_by_xpath("./div/span[2]")
        for entry in entries_of_the_row:
            table_file.write(f"{entry.text}\t")
        table_file.write("\n")
table_file.close()
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I will try the code and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Your variable `rows` will return, based on the HTML, a single element, just the `a` tag surrounding the table. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: I am gathering all the rows so then I can write row by row in the txt file

Comment: @JorgeHB I understand, but my point is the xpath `"//div[@class = 'property-table__list']/a"` doesn't gather rows, it just returns the `a` element.

Comment: I am not trying to return any element. Also, when I say I want to gather al the rows, maybe it is a bit inaccurate. When I select "a" WebElement, I am pointing to the root of all the information that the row contains. So, when I put "find_elements", I am pointing to all the nodes that follow that xpath direction in the HTML. So, if each "a" element gathers information of one row, it should do the trick for all of them. I am used to working with selenium commands of "Xpath" so I am sure this works.

Comment: Thanks JorgeHB for your answer. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work fully but i appreciate your help and your time spent!